# Count lines of code in a Django Project

Tags: python, django

Is there an easy way to count the lines of code you have written for your django project?

Edit: The shell stuff is cool, but how about on Windows?

Comment: Do you mean all lines in any *.py files in the project or just lines of code that *you* wrote, excluding any scaffolding code?

Comment: @Andrew, arn't the DJango distribution files usually housed away from the site-root anyway?

Comment: @Andrew Hare, yeah I just want to find out the lines of code I have written.  Really just the view.py, model.py and urls.py files would work ... although that would still miss a lot of code in my context_processors and so on. 

@Aiden Bell yeah they are.

Comment: You should fix the "pythong" tag.

Comment: I often accidentally type `pythong` at the shell... Freudian?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yep:

```
shell]$ find /my/source -name "*.py" -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

Job's a good 'un.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look at [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) -- it's not Django specific but it supports Python.  It can show you lines counts for actual code, comments, blank lines, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Aiden's answer, and with a bit of help in [a question of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133698/find-name-pattern-that-matches-multiple-patterns), I ended up with this god-awful mess:

```
# find the combined LOC of files
# usage: loc Documents/fourU py html
function loc {
    #find $1 -name $2 -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l
    namelist=''
    let i=2
    while [ $i -le $# ]; do
        namelist="$namelist -name \"*.$@[$i]\""
        if [ $i != $# ]; then
            namelist="$namelist -or "
        fi
        let i=i+1
    done
    #echo $namelist
    #echo "find $1 $namelist" | sh
    #echo "find $1 $namelist" | sh | xargs cat
    echo "find $1 $namelist" | sh | xargs cat | wc -l
}
```

which allows you to specify any number of extensions you want to match.  As far as I can tell, it outputs the right answer, but... I thought this would be a one-liner, else I wouldn't have started in bash, and it just kinda grew from there.

I'm sure that those more knowledgable than I can improve upon this, so I'm going to put it in community wiki.

Comment: loc() { 
        D=$1; shift
        echo "$@" | xargs -n 1 echo | sed 's,^, -or -name *.,' | xargs find $D -type f | xargs cat | wc -l
}

Comment: Alright, oneliner: echo py html | xargs -n 1 echo | sed 's,^, -or -name *.,' | xargs find Documents -type f | xargs cat | wc -l

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about shift!  As I said, this answer is in community wiki, so you can edit it directly... if not, I might get around to fixing it later.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the wc command on unix.

Answer (score 0):

Get wc command on Windows using GnuWin32 (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)

> wc *.py