# Executing grep on multiple find results

Tags: shell, grep, cygwin

My question is rather similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133698/find-name-pattern-that-matches-multiple-patterns), except that I'm executing a `grep` search on multiple `find` queries. (I have to do this because I have to submit my command to the live servers, and I'd like to tinker with them as little as possible.)

Here is my query:

`find /c/some/dir/ -iname "*html" -o -iname "*tpl" -exec grep -inH 'search_string' {} \;`

With the -o option, the grep search returns all of the instances of "search_string" in the files that end with tpl. It completely ignores the html extensions I passed in...

Has anyone encountered this? How do I tell find to execute the grep on both html and tpl extensions?

(I'm running Cygwin, which has had some Windows translation issues in the past, so that may be a culprit...)

Comment: you meant `"*.html"` right?

Comment: yup, you're exactly right

Comment: so fix those problems, and try again.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your comment. "*html" is a superset of "*.html", so it will capture the html extension and more. (For instance, it would capture xhtml and such.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to group the two `-iname` clauses, like this:

```
find /c/some/dir/ \( -iname "*html" -o -iname "*tpl" \) -exec grep -inH 'search_string' {} \;
```

The logical or has a lower precedence, which means the `-exec` bits only apply to your `-iname "*tpl"` clause.

Comment: This is what I thought, but I didn't know how the statements were parsed. I'll try this now and accept the answer if appropriate. Thanks!