# Find different types of files and move to a specific directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, move

Finding *.mkv and *.mp4 works

```
find /home6/movies/ -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv'
```

but moving them for some reason partially fails and moves only mkv files

```
find /home6/movies/ -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -exec mv {} /home6/archive/ \;
```

Am I using an incorrect find switch "-o" for this task?

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: It's because they are bad people). I also do not understand them. Downvoting without an explanation is a bad practice. I like your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to surround the or expression in parentheses so the exec applies to both matches.

This is a similar question: [`find -name` pattern that matches multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133698/find-name-pattern-that-matches-multiple-patterns)

```
find /home6/movies/ \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' \) -exec mv {} /home6/archive/ \;
```